# I calculated an average in crossfilter, but it's wrong. I can't understand why. Can you point out my error?

Tags: crossfilter

You can see my gistup here: http://bl.ocks.org/markarios/058f85800d598fc9f2b6

While checking reductio, I calculated the average PPI per device type and the following code is producing the wrong result. The only thing I can think of is that I some how need to use the index of ppi_device_sum[i].key but I'm not sure how to reference that.

Thanks advance for your time!

```
// What's the average PPI per device?
write("");
write("Average PPI By Type");
for (var i = 0; i < type_device_count.length; i++) {
write(ppi_device_sum[i].key + "(s): " + ppi_device_sum[i].value/type_device_count[i].value);
};
```

*Product Types*

tablet(s): 7

desktop monitor(s): 4

laptop(s): 2

smartphone(s): 2

desktop(s): 1

*Total PPI by Device Type*

tablet(s): 1997

smartphone(s): 770

desktop monitor(s): 444

laptop(s): 350

desktop(s): 108

*Average PPI By Type*

tablet(s): 285.2857142857143 (correct)

smartphone(s): 192.5 (incorrect, should be 385)

desktop monitor(s): 222 (incorrect, should be 111)

laptop(s): 175 (correct)

desktop(s): 108 (correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to sort your arrays by key before you iterate through them so that their keys are in the same order ([JavaScript Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method is fine for this).

If you find any problems with the calculations in Reductio, please file an [issue on Github](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio/issues). It is very raw at the moment. I will be integrating it into a larger application in the next couple of weeks, so it will be getting more use and eyes on it at that point.

One other note: In your gist you are doing something that makes me think you are working under a very common misconception about how Crossfilter works. It's not exactly intuitive, but this

```
// calculate the number of device types
    var type_count = type.group().reduceCount().size();

// how many of each device are there?
    var type_device_count = type.group()
    .reduceCount()
    .top(type_count);
```

is doing the same thing as this

```
// Build the Crossfilter group.
var typeGroup = type.group();                    // .reduceCount() is the default

// calculate the number of device types
var type_count = typeGroup.size();               // Now redundant

// how many of each device are there?
var type_device_count = typeGroup.top(Infinity); // Returns all groups
```

The later is the better way to do things because once you've created a Crossfilter group, that group will be updated when new data is added to the Crossfilter and when you filter on other dimensions. So typeGroup.size() and typeGroup.top(Infinity) will return different results as the contents and filters on your Crossfilter change. Keeping these groups updated uses resources, so you want to create as few dimensions and groups as possible to accomplish your task.

Comment: thanks very much. I actually found the error in my code using reductio, which I'm very thankful for. I felt like an idiot when I saw my code was producing wrong averages.

Comment: thanks again. that sorting worked. I also took your advice. Here's my working version. http://bl.ocks.org/markarios/058f85800d598fc9f2b6 .Cheers, Mark